# How to proceed with a problem with a professor and class structure as a whole

Tags: united-states, teaching-assistant, professionalism

I am a teaching assistant for an introductory summer term class. I have not previously been a TA for this specific course, but have worked within this department and typically teach an accelerated introductory course for pre-major students during the spring and fall. Since the start of the semester, I have had concerns about working under the professor teaching this class. I and the other TA for the class had no direct communication with him until the third week of the semester, despite a weekly meeting being the norm for all classes, and this only occurred at the strong recommendation of the department head.

This means that I and the other TA were having to grade without a proper rubric since one was not provided for us, nor were we given expectations of student abilities such that we could create our own, and we have had to very frequently improvise during lab sections due to course material being incomplete or unfinished until just hours before the morning labs start. Part of my training to be a teaching assistant explicitly stated that course material should be reviewed no less than 24 hours before the upcoming lab so that any errors or concerns can be addressed. I have only been able to properly craft a lesson plan for my students once this entire semester.

Trying to raise concerns with this professor falls on deaf ears, and this does not seem to be a pattern unique to me or the other teaching assistant I work with. Through vague references, I have been made aware that the head of the undergraduate program has been shadowing lectures and the two have been talking to one another. Advisement and suggestions have definitely been made and ignored, including a reminder that one cannot retroactively mandate attendance if it is not stated in the syllabus. This has instead evidently been replaced with forcibly calling on students during lectures to get their opinions about the lecture material.

As we rapidly approach the midterm exam, I have strong misgivings about this class and the performance of its students. I do not feel this is a failure to prepare on behalf of my students. I feel that they just have not been prepared at all. Per the last meeting I had with the professor, I was made aware that the lab sections are apparently seeing more attendance than the lectures. On a good week, I see just over half the class between the two lab sections offered. As one of the two primary graders for all assignments, I have seen that around 10% of students fail to submit anything weekly, including quizzes and assignments. Grades overall look good, but this is due to the open permissive use of ChatGPT and other generative AI tools, which notably will *not* be allowed on this upcoming exam.

I have had students express that they do not understand what they are learning, and I can only do so much in the time I have with them each week. I'm truthfully at a loss for what to do and whether I *can* do anything further in the position I'm in besides document issues as they arise and maybe raise them with someone who will listen. I've left out a lot of details for the sake of brevity, but I would greatly appreciate any and all insight, advice, or guidance on this matter.